# progress bar perform step in parallel foreach

Tags: parallel-processing, progress-bar

I have a simple code that does this:

```
     private List<DicomImage> img = new List<DicomImage>();



  Parallel.ForEach(ofdmulti.FileNames, filename =>
                {
                    img.Add(new DicomImage(filename));
                    Progress_Bar_Loading_Images.PerformStep();
                } 
                );
```

When I execute it, I get an error:

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Progress_Bar_Loading_Images' accessed from a 
thread other than the thread it was created on."

How can I solve that without removing the progress bar? I really need it to show the progress

Answer (score 0):

When you use Parallel.Foreach, each iteration (or a group of it) is perfomed on another thread (luckly on a different processor) concurrently. However, progressbar is working on main thread (or GUI thread) so you need to synchronize your threads after each call to progress bar. 
An important thing to mention in here is synchronizing for each step is slow and pointless.So I suggest you to put a condition dependent on the modulus of an index to say "synchronize for each 10 steps".

Comment: Thanks, so how do you Synchronize in terms of Code?

Comment: You need to create a lock object and call progress bar in a locked section. You may searched for "paralel.foreach synchronization". hope it works